# How to create a stream with name using RTMPClient on RED5 Client

Tags: red5, red5pro

I am trying create a stream with a preferred name say 'mylive' with RED5 Client. using RTMPClient, how can I do this?

RTMPClient has createStream(callBack) , but it seems to there is noway to pass the name for my stream.

say i want create stream on my server like rtmp://localhost/live/mylive